# Calculating Font Size

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i have UITextView ( 480 w * 320 h) where we can set various font size using font size  picker and have a buffered UITextView ( 1800 w * 1200 h) . Let say if i set 30 font size for my first text  view need to set font size for buffered text view . How can i calculate font size for buffered textview??

Answer (score 0):

How do you "calculate" it? However you want. You'll have to rephrase that part of the question.

Here's one way to set the font size once you decide what to make it:

```
CGFloat fontSize = 16.0f;
UIFont* changedFont = [myuitextview.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
myuitextview.font = changedFont;
```

Comment: thanks for reply  , i want o calculate relative Font size for my bigger text view .

Comment: @santosh you still haven't explained what you mean by "relative font size". Until you do, I can't help you.

Comment: see i have two text views one is (480 x 320 ) and second one is (1800 x 1200 ) . I have set 30 as font size for first text view and it has some text . I want to set same text for second text view , how ever as second one has large resolution so need to increase font size . I need know how much size i should be increased so that text will be set properly. ( lets say first one has two lines then second  one should also have  two lines )

Comment: @santosh  I guess you could try something like dividing the dimensions to come up with a ratio, which you can use as a multiplier on the existing font size.